# Databricks Spark Write Behavior - Files like _committed and _start

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm facing an issue when writing data to **S3** using **Databricks Spark**, where I'm observing additional files such as _committed and _start alongside my actual data files. My implementation doesn't involve Delta Lake, and I'm using a standard Spark write operation.

**Environment:**

- Databricks Runtime: 9.1
- Apache Spark: 3.1.2
- Storage: S3

Observations:

- Files like _committed and _start are present alongside my actual data files in the S3 output location.
- I'm not using Delta Lake in my implementation.

Question:

- Can someone explain why these files (_committed and _start) are being generated, and what is their purpose in a standard Spark write operation on Databricks?
- Are there any specific Databricks Runtime or Databricks File System (DBFS) features that might be causing this behaviour?
- Is there any way to omit the files ?

Comment: refer this this https://docs.databricks.com/en/lakehouse/acid.html

Comment: like I have mentioned in question it is not Delta implementation that I am looking, its just a plain write operation on S3 bucket via Databricks.  @JayashankarGS

Comment: Read the documentation once again `Databricks uses Delta Lake by default for all reads and writes and builds upon the ACID guarantees provided by the open source Delta Lake protocol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _committed and _start commands alongside your actual data files in a standard Spark write operation on Databricks maybe related to the transactional behavior of the Databricks File System  when writing to external storage like S3.

Let me help you ansser the questions,
the purpose of these files might be specific to the internal workings of Databricks and DBFS during write operations. but I checked and Unfortunately, Databricks does not always expose detailed documentation.

Maybe Upgrading or changing the Databricks Runtime version might lead to variations in this behavior.

I think there might not be a straightforward way to omit these files, you could consider post-processing steps after the write operation to filter out these auxiliary files from your final dataset.

```html
import requests

# Databricks REST API endpoint for listing files
api_url = "https://<your-databricks-instance>/api/2.0/dbfs/list"

# Databricks personal access token for authentication
token = "<your-personal-access-token>"

# DBFS directory path
directory_path = "/path/to/your/directory"

# Make API request to list files in the directory
response = requests.get(
    api_url,
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"},
    params={"path": directory_path}
)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the response JSON
    files = response.json().get("files", [])

    # Filter files based on your criteria
    filtered_files = [file for file in files if not file["path"].endswith(("_committed", "_start"))]

    # Perform actions with the filtered files (e.g., delete, move, etc.)
    for file in filtered_files:
        print(f"Processing file: {file['path']}")

else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, post processing steps can we handle it via code or this is something we have to do manually.

Comment: yeah you can automate the cleanup or filtering of  files through code, let me give you a sample snipp in answer section.

Comment: Thanks, in current implementation of EMR we did the same thing filtered out _SUCCESS file, so same I will do it for Databricks' cluster impl. Thanks a ton.